# how can i use dynamic programming to optimize this code

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, optimization, dynamic-programming

Daulat Ram is an affluent business man. After demonetization, IT raid was held at his accommodation in which all his money was seized. He is very eager to gain his money back, he started investing in certain ventures and earned out of them. On the first day, his income was Rs. X, followed by Rs. Y on the second day. Daulat Ram observed his growth as a function and wanted to calculate his income on the Nth day.

The function he found out was FN = FN-1 + FN-2 + FN-1×FN-2

Given his income on day 0 and day 1, calculate his income on the Nth day (yeah Its that simple).

INPUT:

The first line of input consists of a single integer T denoting number of test cases.

Each of the next T lines consists of three integers F0, F1 and N respectively.

OUTPUT:

For each test case, print a single integer FN, as the output can be large, calculate the answer modulo 109+7.

CONSTRAINTS:

1 ≤ T ≤ 105

0 ≤ F0, F1, N ≤ 109

```
def function(x1):

 if x1==2:  return fnc__1+fnc__0*fnc__1+fnc__0
 elif x1==1: return fnc__1
 elif x1==0: return fnc__0

 return function(x1-1)+function(x1-2)*function(x1-1)+function(x1-2)


for i in range(int(input())):  #input() is the no of test cases
 rwINput = input().split()

 fnc__0 =int(rwINput[0])
 fnc__1 = int(rwINput[1])

 print(function(int(rwINput[2])))
```

Comment: @hiroprotagonist: actually memoization can be a form of easy (cheap) dynamic programming.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem: oh, right. thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Someone gave this answer to me and it worked but i don't know how?Complexity O(logn)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define mod 1000000007
long long int power(long long int,long long int);
void mult(long long int[2][2],long long int[2][2]);
int main()
{
    int test;
    scanf("%d",&test);
    while(test--)
    {
        int n;
    int pp,p;
    scanf("%d%d%d",&pp,&p,&n);
    long long int A[2][2] = {{1,1},{1,0}};
    n = n-1;
    long long int B[2][2] = {{1,0},{0,1}};
    while(n>0)
    {
        if(n%2==1)
            mult(B,A);
        n = n/2;
        mult(A,A);
    }
   long long int result = ((power(pp+1,B[0][1])*power(p+1,B[0][0]))%mod - 1 + mod)%mod;
   printf("%lld\n",result);
   }



}

long long int power(long long int a,long long int b)
{
    long long int result = 1;
    while(b>0)
    {
        if(b%2==1)
            result = (result*a)%mod;
        a = (a*a)%mod;
        b = b/2;
    }
    return result;

}
void mult(long long int A[2][2],long long int B[2][2])
{
    long long int C[2][2];
    C[0][0] = A[0][0]*B[0][0] + A[0][1]*B[1][0];
    C[0][1] = A[0][0]*B[0][1] + A[0][1]*B[1][1];
    C[1][0] = A[1][0]*B[0][0] + A[1][1]*B[1][0];
    C[1][1] = A[1][0]*B[0][1] + A[1][1]*B[1][1];
    A[0][0] = C[0][0]%(mod-1);
    A[0][1] = C[0][1]%(mod-1);
    A[1][0] = C[1][0]%(mod-1);
    A[1][1] = C[1][1]%(mod-1);
}
```

Comment: He must have spent quite a while analysing the problem to find an analytic solution in terms of the two input numbers and of a matrix which only depends on n (computed in the loop) . The function "mult" is a matrix multiplication A := A* B [modulo mod-1].

Answer (score 3):

a simple way to optimize is to cache the results of your function. python provides a mechanism for just hat with its [`lru_cache`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache). all you need to do is decorate your function with this:

```
from functools import lru_cache

@lru_cache()
def function(n, F0=1, F1=2):

    if n == 0:
        return F0
    elif n == 1:
        return F1
    else:
        f1 = function(n-1, F0, F1)
        f2 = function(n-2, F0, F1)
        return f1+f2 + f1*f2
```

you can tweak `lru_cache` a bit for your needs. and it plays very nice with the python garbage collector as it stores `WeakRefs` to your objects only.

test cases:

```
for i in range(7):
    print('{}: {:7d}'.format(i, function(i)))
```

prints:

```
0:       1
1:       2
2:       5
3:      17
4:     107
5:    1943
6:  209951
```

to get your answer modulo an integer (not clear about the modulus in your question) you can do this:

```
MOD = 10**9 + 7 # ???

@lru_cache()
def function(n, F0=1, F1=2):

    if n == 0:
        return F0
    elif n == 1:
        return F1
    else:
        f1 = function(n-1, F0, F1)
        f2 = function(n-2, F0, F1)
        return (f1+f2 + f1*f2) % MOD
```

Comment: It didnot work . For example try 1 2 4 desired output is 117 but doing that gives 11 . explanation:F0=1

F1=2

F2=1 + 2 + 1×2 = 5

F3=2 + 5 + 2×5 = 17

F4=5 + 17 + 5×17 = 107

Comment: @ShailabSingh: updated. you did not provide the starting conditions for your recursion. now with `F0 = 1, F1 = 2` everything is fine.

Comment: @ShailabSingh: could you be more precise? when does it start to go wrong? how is it not working? what are you comparing the results to?

Comment: @ShailabSingh Can you add the full problem statement to question? Quite often the sites ask you to give the result as modulus of some large number which might explain the issue with large input.

Comment: does this now reproduce your results? or is there something in your question that i am missing?

Comment: time limit is not exceeded but the answer is wrong that way

Comment: what exactly is wrong? where did you get a wrong answer (starting from n=?)? did you restart your interpreter (if you change the function, the cache may have wrong values)? and you keep mentioning a time limit. what exactly is this limit? and is the `MOD` correct? you question says `109+7` but that is not prime; `10**9+7` is. how do you expect any help without that information? and how do you know it is wrong? what result do you have?

Comment: MOD is 10**9+7 and i got the answers wrong from the inputs which are hidden. Try it for yourself https://www.hackerearth.com/codathon-nitbhopal/algorithm/recurrence/

Comment: mathematically speaking it is not possible for this function to produce the correct results for the first 7 entries and then run out of whack. there are just not enough degrees of freedom. the problem must lie somewhere else. and that is not for me to find out. sorry.

Comment: There is one thing that might cause the problem... you need to do `f1 = function(n-1, F0, F1)` and `f2 = function(n-2, F0, F1)`. Otherwise non-standard `F0` and `F1` won't be propagated to the recursive calls. Also I guess, the modulo should be applied to the end result only but that's just a hunch.

Comment: @swenzel: i agree in the propagation of `F0, F1`. but applying mod at the very end only is a bad idea efficiency-wise. mod a prime does calculations in a filed. addition and multiplication work as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You could just start execute the function and assign `f1` to `f0` and result to `f1`. Iterate over this `n` times and the desired result is in `f0`:

```
MOD = 10**9 + 7

for _ in range(int(input())):
    f0, f1, n = (int(x) for x in input().split())
    for _ in range(n):
        f0, f1 = f1, (f0 + f1 + f0 * f1) % MOD

    print(f0)
```

Input:

```
8
1 2 0
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 2 6
10 13 100
```

Output:

```
1
2
5
17
107
1943
209951
276644752
```

Comment: time limit exceeded! btw dont ask me for the inputs just see the constraints!

Comment: @ShailabSingh Updated answer based on your edits to questions. Exceeding time limit with previous answer was expected because size of the numbers weren't limited in any way. While Python integers don't have any limit operations get quite slow. I'm assuming that with modulo 109+7 you actually mean `10**9 + 7` since it's commonly used with this kind of problems,

Comment: time limit exceeded again!!

Answer (score -1):

I know this post is old, but I want to point out that an important issue has been eluded: the function quickly gets huge values, and only a modulo is required. The modulo of a sum or of a product can be computed with the sum or product of the modulos. So the only way to get a correct answer for a big N is to store the modulos, instead of the Fn!

Here is my view on how dynamic programming should be used. Dynamic programming is just about caching the results in order to avoid recomputing all sub-branches of the recursion tree. Storing the successive Fn is everything that's needed. If the algorithm only needs to be used once, you even don't have to store the whole array here: compute f0 and f1, and keep the last two computed values (with the modulo), to find the result with a simple loop. If the algorithm is run multiple times, and the result has still not been computed, you just need to retrieve the last two computed values (a variable to store the index of the last computed value would be useful) in order to restart from there.

Comment: PS: the wrong values may be due to an overflow (values too big because the modulo is only computed at the end)